# How this (impossible?) object is called?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

If we take a square and glue together two opposite sides we get topological cylinder.

If we take a square and glue together the two pairs of opposite sides, we get a torus.

But what if we take a disc and glue together the opposite points on its edge while keeping the internal geometry flat?

Does such object/manifold have a name? I suspect, it's just Klein bottle, am I correct?

Comment: Topologically, you get a [real projective plane](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane).

Comment: Maybe because you were talking topologically, and then said "flat", which isn't a topological concept? Makes the question look poorly written? Just a guess, I haven't voted on your question.

Comment: @StinkingBishop if we embed it in 4D space, we get Klein bottle, yes?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think, you answered my question, the linked article describes what I was asking for.

Comment: Real projective plane is *not* homeomorphic to Klein bottle. For example, they have a different [Euler characteristic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the [real projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) or sometimes just "projective plane".

It can be proved to be different from the Klein bottle. What you described glues the edges like this:

[image: PP gluing]

(Note that if each point is glued to the opposite point, it doesn't matter whether we start with a square or a circle, since they are topologically equivalent.)

To get a Klein bottle we have to glue it differently:

[image: Klein gluing]

Comment: Topologically equivalent, yes but would their internal geometry be different?

Comment: Are there named 4D manifolds, topologically equivalent to this projective plane?

Comment: Klein bottle diagram: looks like all arrows point to one point, no?

Comment: I don't think you can keep the geometry flat while doing this gluing.

Comment: @Anixx Anything topologically equivalent to the projective plane is a 2D manifold. You mean a locally flat embedding of the projective plane into 4D space. (For comparison, the Clifford torus is a locally flat embedding of a torus into 4D.) Also yes, in the diagram for the Klein bottle, all four corners represent the same point in the quotient space.

Comment: Okay, so what I was asking about has multiple names that I never heard before, such as Cross-capped disk, Roman surface and Boy's surface.

Comment: I think, a manifold with constant positive curvature can be made though (for instance, a sphere where the two hemispheres are identified with each other has this property).

Comment: [This excellent post by David Speyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4509605/25554) addresses the question of whether the projective plane is flat (it isn't) and why not.