# Is the real projective plane flat?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I am not sure if I am using the correct name, what I mean by the real projective plane is a flat square of space in which the upper edge is identified with the left/right reversed bottom edge and vice versa for the left and right edges. I would normally assume that it is flat, for the same reasons a torus is flat (I am based on intuition, I still  have zero  understanding of topology or differential geometry).

But if I look at what happens to an arrow moving up diagonally, like in the figure below, I find that angles are not preserved. I attempted to draw what happens with an arrow that moved diagonally and disappears on the upper right corner to reappear at the bottom left one. Or did I do something wrong?

[image]

Comment: "A torus" is certainly not flat. There *is* a flat metric structure on the torus, that comes from your identification space (or taking the induced metric as the torus naturally sits in $\Bbb R^4$). The torus is a special case (because the vertex angles add up to $2\pi$). By your reasoning, a $g$-holed torus for any $g\ge 2$ might be flat, but that's not possible (say, by Gauss-Bonnet). The projective plane is, in fact, a space of constant positive curvature. If it could be flat, then you'd get a flat structure on the sphere, and that too is impossible (by Gauss-Bonnet).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I cannot follow you much, I read that a torus, or at least a square with top and bottom edges identified (and same with the left and right edges) is flat. I am interested in the intrinsic geometry of such flat square., or rather, in the one whose edges are reversed.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny: What is your definition of "flat"?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny: What Ted Shifrin is saying is that it doesn't make sense to ask whether "the" torus is flat.  That is, you have to specify which torus you mean.  A torus in 3-dimensional space cannot be flat.  However, there are tori in 4-dimensional space that are.

Comment: @JesseMadnick May be that is the problem. Let us settle for a space in which an object can move around without being deformed or feel stress, one in which you do not feel any gravitational force due to the curvature of space

Comment: @Wolphramjonny: Respectfully, I think the larger problem is that you're using vague terms.  When you say "space," what dimension do you have in mind?  When you say "flat," what is your precise mathematical definition?  You should tell us these things.  Also, concepts like "stress" and "gravitational force" belong to physics, and aren't necessary for questions that are purely about geometry.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny does this article convey what you might mean by 'flat' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold?

Comment: @JesseMadnick I am being vague because I do not have that much knowledge, I am trying to explain with the words I know, it would be great if you try to understand my confusion rather than start blaming me for not being an expert.

Comment: @AlvinJin yes, I believe that is exactly what I mean! So, is a flat 2 D square with those boundary conditions locally flat everywhere (zero curvature)?

Comment: I already told you the answer is NO. When you parallel translate a vector around your loop it reverses direction; when you go around a second time, it returns to its original position.

Comment: It appears that you understand why your picture does not make real projective space flat. The angles at the corners (vertices) do not add up to $2\pi$. So the question becomes whether there is another way to glue the sides of a square or some other $2$-dimensional shapes so that the result is topologically real projective space but with a flat metric where the angles add up to $2\pi$ at every point. As @TedShifrin points out, by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, the answer is no. On the other hand, the answer is yes for the torus.

Comment: @TedShifrin But then I do not understand why you said a torus is flat but is not flat. May be I am calling it a torus, I mean the flat square in which a triangle internal angles add to 180, and its borders are identified. Same with what I call a "projective plane", but may be I am not using a precise terminology.

Comment: I'm sorry I brought up the non-flat torus. The usual torus we all draw and visualize — the surface of a doughnut in space — is *not flat*. Your identification space is flat; it's fine. For the torus only.

Comment: @Deane now I understand! Thanks a lot for your uncryptic answer.

Comment: I don't think a topological graph like the one in the question is designed to convey any information about angles. You could just as easily draw a circular disk and identify opposite points along its boundary; this too would be a model of a projective plane but it would not bend the arrow regardless of which point on the boundary you sent it through. To put it another way, your use of your figure implies that the projective plane has two lines (the diagonals) with different properties around them than other lines, which is certainly not the idea of a projective plane.

Comment: @DavidK the reason I called it a projective plane was because I found an analogy with my diagram, may be that was a mistake. I meant an Euclidean square with the boundaries identified that way. Because I know that a Mobius strip is flat and the reversed boundary has no local consequences, I thought it would be the same if I had the other two boundaries  reversed too.

Comment: Just to be explicit, your diagram does show a singular structure on the projective plane that is flat everywhere except two cone points (the images of the vertices, which are identified in pairs); each cone point has incident angle $\pi$, hence total curvature $2\pi - \pi = \pi$. The total curvature of the projective plane is therefore $2\pi$.

Comment: I've seen the exact same figure (using a square) used as a projective plane; I just had assumed that it referred to the pointwise topology (connectivity) and not to any kind of Euclidean structure, even locally. But I suppose there could be projective planes that I am not familiar with.

Comment: @DavidK The square is a metric space (as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$), and this induces a metric on the quotient (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Quotient_metric_spaces . ) This is a Riemannian metric away from the two corners; the two corners are "orbifold points". I tried to explain this in a more elementary way in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}\def\PP{\mathbb{P}}$What people usually mean by flat is "having a metric with [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) zero". Informally, this means that if you measure distances on your space, it locally looks like $\RR^2$. The OP sounds like someone who isn't familiar with these ideas, so I'm going to try to give a leisurely introduction. These issues were already raised in comments by Deane and Andrew D. Hwang.

Let $M$ be a surface with a metric and let $p$ be a point of $M$. Let $C_r$ be the set of points at distance $r$ from $M$, for $r$ small enough, this is a circle. Let $|C_r|$ be the perimeter of that circle. Then the curvature of $M$ at $p$ can be defined as
$$K(p) := \lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{2 \pi r - |C_r|}{\pi r^3/3}. \qquad (\ast)$$

For a first example, if $M = \RR^2$, then $|C_r|  = 2 \pi r$ and the curvature is $0$. For a second example, if $M$ is a sphere of radius $R$ and $p$ is the north pole, then $C_r$ is the circle of latitude at angle $\tfrac{r}{R}$ from the pole, and $|C_r| = 2 \pi R \sin \tfrac{r}{R} = 2 \pi \left( r - \tfrac{r^3}{6 R^2} + \cdots \right)$ by the Taylor series of sine, so $M$ has curvature $\tfrac{1}{R^2}$.

By the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem), for a compact surface $M$, we have
$$\int_M K dA = 2 \pi \chi(M)$$
where $dA$ is with respect to the area coming from the metric and $\chi(M)$ is the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic). For example, the Euler characteristic of a sphere is $2$. The sphere of radius $R$ has area $4 \pi R^2$ and curvature $\tfrac{1}{R^2}$ as computed above, and we have $4 \pi R^2 \cdot \tfrac{1}{R^2} = (2 \pi) \cdot 2$, as predicted by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

In particular, if $K$ is identically zero, then $\chi(M)$ must be $0$. This happens for the torus and the Klein bottle, but not for $\RR \PP^2$; the Euler characteristic of $\RR \PP^2$ is $1$.

---

Okay, but what does this have to do with drawing squares with identified sides? Let's start with an easier question: Cut out the template below and glue the sides together. You'll get the surface of a cube, which is toplogically a sphere, and it will look flat. Why doesn't this violate Gauss-Bonnet?

[image]

If you use definition $(\ast)$ above, you will find that the curvature of your cube surface is $0$ at the interior of any face. You will even find that it is $0$ in the interior of every edge: If $p$ is in the interior of an edge, and $r$ is shorter than the distance from $p$ to either end of the edge, then you will find that $|C_r| = 2 \pi r$.

However, if $p$ is one of the eight vertices of the cube, then life is very different! In this case, $C_r$ is the union of three quarter arcs, so $|C_r| = \tfrac{3}{2} \pi r$. So the limit in $(\ast)$ blows up very quickly! Your cube surface has infinite curvature at the eight vertices, and $0$ everywhere else.

So, we need a version of Gauss-Bonnet for spaces with corners. For simplicity, let's do spaces like our cube surface, which are curvature zero everywhere except at finitely many points $v_1$, $v_2$, ..., $v_n$. Let
$$k_i = \lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{2 \pi r - |C_r|}{r}$$
where $C_r$ is the circle of radius $r$ around $k_i$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n k_i = 2 \pi \chi(M).$$
In our cube example, we get $8$ points where $k_1=k_2=\cdots=k_8 = \tfrac{\pi}{2}$. And $\tfrac{\pi}{2} \cdot 8 = (2 \pi) \cdot \chi(S^2)$, as predicted. (Exercise: Prove this formula for polyhedra! You will learn what Euler characteristic has to do with [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic)! This case is known as [Descartes' Angle Deficit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_defect#Descartes.27_theorem).)

And this is what happens when you glue a square to itself as in your figure. The resulting surface has two corner points, coming from the $4$ corners of the square. The circle of radius $r$ around such a corner has perimeter $\pi r$; on the square, it looks like two quarter arcs in two of the opposite corners. So we have $\pi + \pi = (2 \pi) \cdot \chi(\RR\PP^2)$, as predicted.